# webDAV IIS6 Authentication not working with anonymous disabled

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have been trying to implement a webDAV connection on an existing IIS ASP.NET web site. This issue surrounds permissions and connectivity when "Enable anonymous access" is unchecked and disabled.

I have tried every combination available. The server is w2k3 Web Edition, no AD, IIS6, so "Digest authentication for Windows domain servers" is not an option in the Authenticated Access section of Authentication Methods of the Virtual Directory I am sharing in the web site.

I have read about and tested the Registry Edit of the following key, \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\services\WebClient\Parameters\BasicAuthLevel

and change the value to 2

agianst each possible authentication method. It seems to disable connectivity more then helping.

I am trying to map a path to a virtual directory on the web server, a function of the webDAV protocol, works great if anonymous access is enabled, but obviously can not be for this project.

I would like to at least get the Windows Authentication to work and disbale Anonymous Access.

I have been testing this on both a development server and production server and the behavior is consistent. On a Win7 OS I can not get the Windows Authentication dialog box to appear.

A few tests on XP, the box appeared but would not authenticate, but this may have been related to other config issues.

I have also tested with Permissions to the Everyone group just to see if I can connect.

Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I found this article that explains a portion of the problem and work around though not entirely fitting for the issue explained above.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found this article that explains a portion of the problem and work around though not entirely fitting for the issue explained above. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280/en-us

Answer (score 1):

Try adding permissions for Network_services and the IIS User on that box.  that has always gotten me over the permissions issues I have faced.  You need to add these from within IIS as at least with IIS 7 it seems to over rule the permissions from windows explorer.  Not sure if IIS 6 does the same but I just do it by default now.

Comment: Thanks, but both of those accounts have permissions now.

Comment: Actually they have had premissions all along and still no luck.